# GAE datastore in python won't find entities I know exist

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datastore, gql

If I execute the following code:

```
def post(self):
    name = self.request.get('username')
    password = self.request.get('password')
    user_is = users.all().filter('name =', name).get()
    params = dict()
    if user_is:
        hashword = user_is.password
        if check_password(username, password, hashword):
            key = db.Key.from_path('users', str(user_is.key().id()))
            c = db.get(key)
            secret_cookie = make_cookie_secret(c)
            self.response.headers.add_header('Set-Cookie', "user_id=%s; Path=/" % secret_cookie)
            self.redirect('/blog/userwelcomepage')
        else:
            params['passworderror'] = "Invalid username/password"
            self.render("pagelogin.html", **params)
    else:
        params['usernameerror'] = "No such user"
        self.render("pagelogin.html", **params)
```

The datastore can never find anything in the filter query. I have created 2 special pages to ensure the data I'm looking for does indeed exist, one that iterates off of `u=db.GqlQuery(SELECT * FROM users)` I pass u into a jinja template that iterates

`{% for i in u %}i.username<br>i.password<br>i.email{% endfor %}`

I see the expected username.

Then I created a jinja template that takes in:

```
users.all()
```

Then I iterate:

```
{% for i in users %}{% if i.username == "Joe"%}Yay{% else %}nope{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

The username I am looking for, Joe, generates a "Yay".

Why can jinja draw a correct match, but Gql cannot? No matter what I do any search that filters whether by "where" or by .filter returns None

Searches by key are fine and work as expected.

Comment: Also, users.username is db.StringProperty(), so it should be indexed

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
user_is = users.all().filter('username =', name).get()
```

Comment: That's my guess, too.